# Insert multiple value laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello i want insert multiple value in nama_menu

My Code In Controller

```
 public function store(Request $r){
        $history = new History();
        $history->nama = $r->nama;
        $history->provinsi = $r->provinsi;
        $history->nama_menu = $r->nama_menu;
        $history->jumlah = $r->jumlah;
        $history->kota = $r->kota;
        $history->total_pembayaran = $r->total_pembayaran;
        $history->status = $r->status;
        $history->kecamatan = $r->kecamatan;
        $history->kelurahan = $r->kelurahan;
        $history->kodepos = $r->kodepos;
        $history->address = $r->address;
        $history->whatsapp = $r->whatsapp;
        $history->jenis_pembayaran = $r->jenis_pembayaran;
        $history->save();
        
        return redirect(url('/checkout'))->with(['success' => 'berhasil mengirim pesan whatsapp']);;
    }
```

My View Blade
`

###### Orderan Kamu

The Details

```
                    <ul class="order-details-form mb-4">
                        <li><span>Product</span><span>Jumlah</span> <span>Total</span></li>
                        @foreach($fi as $z)
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$z->name}}" name="nama_menu" id="nama_menu">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$z->quantity}}" name="jumlah" id="jumlah">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$z->price * $z->quantity}}" name="total_pembayaran" id="total">

                        <li><span>{{$z->name}}</span ><span>{{$z->quantity}}</span> <span>Rp. {{($z->price * $z->quantity)}}</span></li>
                        @endforeach
                        <li><span>Total</span> <span>Rp. {{ Cart::getTotal() }}</span></li>
                    </ul>
```

`

when i insert the data only nama_menu show one value
[insert fieled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86RC.png)

i want nama_menu insert many [viewblade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLqb8.png)values from view blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert into an array or comma-separate value. it possible way. after that used to implode and explode functions in PHP